# Strip all HTML tags except links

Tags: html, regex, actionscript-3, string, tags

I am trying to write a regular expression to strip all HTML with the exception of links (the `<a href` and `</a>` tags respectively. It does not have to be 100% secure (I am not worried about injection attacks or anything as I am parsing content that has already been approved and published into a [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) movie).

The original "strip tags" regular expression I'm using was `<(.|\n)+?>`, and I tried to modify it to `<([^a]|\n)+?>`, but that of course will allow any tag that has an **a** in it rather than one that has it in the beginning, with a space.

Not that it should really matter, but in case anyone cares to know I am writing this in [ActionScript 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#ActionScript_3.0) for a [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) movie.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<(?!\/?a(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>
```

Try this.  Had something similar for p tags.  Worked for them so don't see why not.  Uses negative lookahead to check that it doesn't match a (prefixed with an optional / character) where (using positive lookahead) a (with optional / prefix) is followed by a > or a space, stuff and then >.  This then matches up until the next > character.  Put this in a subst with

```
s/<(?!\/?a(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>//g;
```

This should leave only the opening and closing a tags

Answer (score 1):

In general there are problems with this approach. Regexes are best for 'flat' text matches - nested data pushes regex engines into areas for which they are not designed. General HTML parsing needs a parser not a regex engine (Google for the difference between regular and context-free languages if you want the full technical details).

It is easy to strip out all tags by replacing /</ and />/ with the empty string or their entity equivalents but selectively filtering HTML using regexes will be vulnerable to a wide range of accidental or malicious inputs breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

I keep going on about it, but there's no way I can recommend [regexr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) too often. It's fantastic for testing this type of things.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
{<(?!i|b|h[1-6]|/i|/b|/h[1-6][\s|>|/])[^>]*>}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
<[^a](.|\n)+?>
```

?

Comment: This keeps <a> but removes </a>

Answer (score -2):

[`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) does this.

Here, I am including all `<a><p><font><b><i><sup>` tags and outputting a tidied version:

```
cat input.htm | tr -d '\n' | php -r '$input=fgets(STDIN); echo strip_tags($input,"<a><p><font><b><i><sup>");' | tidy -i -wrap 0 -o output.htm
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `strip_tags()` is a php function and the question owner asked for an actionscript solution.