# How to remove HTML tag in Java

Tags: java, html, regex

Is there the regular expression that can completely remove a HTML tag? 
By the way, I'm using Java.

Comment: Typing your title into the Search box, I got the following: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+remove+HTML+tag+in+Java ... did you not get the same while you were posting the question?

Comment: I found no duplicates. These questions care about extracting text from HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use a HTML parser instead. I like [htmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), because it gives me a pretty printed version of the HTML.

With htmlCleaner you can do:

```
TagNode root = htmlCleaner.clean( stream );
Object[] found = root.evaluateXPath( "//div[id='something']" );
if( found.length > 0 && found instanceof TagNode ) {
    ((TagNode)found[0]).removeFromTree();
}
```

Comment: Do we need to get any library in-order to use this above code? And root.evaluateXPath( "//div[id='something']" ); in this "something " could be any id rite? please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 24):

There is **[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)** which is a java library made for HTML manipulation. Look at the `clean()` method and the `WhiteList` object. Easy to use solution!

Comment: WOW, you sir, really made my day, i like that, YES! Markdownj, Markdown4J, htmlCleaner.. all of them is ***** sorry.. JSoup is the one and only where you really achieve that with a one-liner:
String plain = new HtmlToPlainText().getPlainText(Jsoup.parse(html));

Comment: A shorter code would be `String plaintext = Jsoup.parse(html).text();`

Comment: @jrarama - Not at all.  `Jsoup.parse(html).text()` remove all of the tags and whitespace, leaving you with a long single line of text only, while `new HtmlToPlainText().getPlainText(Jsoup.parse(html))` formats the text in a simplistic way, keeping line breaks, paragraphs, bullet points, etc.

Comment: @isapir: HtmlToPlainText is not incuded in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.11.3

Comment: That's because HtmlToPlainText is an example, see https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/examples/HtmlToPlainText.java

Answer (score 6):

If you just need to remove tags then you can use this regular expression:

```
content = content.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "");
```

It will remove only tags, but not other HTML stuff. For more complex things you should use parser.

**EDIT**: To avoid problems with HTML comments you can do the following:

```
content = content.replaceAll("<!--.*?-->", "").replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "");
```

Comment: Since you do not use any of the meat characters `.`, `^` and `$`, the `s`- and `m` flags can be omitted.

Comment: This regex is liable to cause mangling if the HTML contains XML comments with embedded '<' or '>' characters.

Answer (score 4):

No. Regular expressions can not by definition parse HTML.

You could use a regex to `s/<[^>]*\>//` or something naive like that but it's going to be insufficient, especially if you're interested in removing the contents of tags.

As another poster said, use an actual HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any HTML parser. The below code removes all HTML comments:

`htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("(?s)<!--.*?-->", "");`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code to remove all html tags...

```
htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""))
```

Comment: This will only remove opening tags and leave closing tags unhandled.

Comment: i never would do a job like that on my own - parsing html into plain-text is really a though job dude..

Comment: It worked for me but maybe depends on the complexity of the tags, comments, scripts, etc. So, for a complex case maybe a html library should be better.