# remove html tags from string using java

Tags: java, html, string

I am writing one program which reads and separate spam and ham emails. Now I am reading it using bufferedreader class of java. I am able to remove any unwanted characters like '(' or '.' etc, using replaceAll() method. I want to remove html tags too, including &amp. How to achieve this!?

thanks

EDIT:
Thanks for the response, but I am already having a regex, how to combine both my needs and put into one. Heres the regex i am using now.

```
lines.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ")
```

Note: I am getting lines from a txt file. 
Any other suggestions plss?!

Comment: I tried Jsoup..but its not working..no complile error, its just simply not working..

Comment: Similar topics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699313/how-to-remove-html-tag-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 37):

Maybe this will work:

```
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

It uses [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions) to remove all HTML tags in a string.

More specifically, it removes all XML like tags from a string. So <1234> will be removed even though it is not a valid HTML tag. But it's good for most intents and purposes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A second call, like `replaceAll("&.*?;","")` would take out entity references.  Although it seems odd to me that one would just want to remove these, rather than translating them back into the characters they represent.

Comment: Very useful and powerful solution .

Comment: Be careful with regex, this is not a full solution. It replaces also unwanted characters -> using this expression for string like "a < b only when c > d" results in "a d".

Comment: True, it's a quick and dirty way of doing it and should be used with caution.

Answer (score 11):

[JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/)

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Comment: For the maven users the link to maven repos for latest version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup

Answer (score 3):

You will want to do some lightweight parsing to strip the HTML:

```
String extractText(String html) throws IOException {
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    ParserDelegator parserDelegator = new ParserDelegator();
    ParserCallback parserCallback = new ParserCallback() {
        public void handleText(final char[] data, final int pos) { 
            list.add(new String(data));
        }
        public void handleStartTag(Tag tag, MutableAttributeSet attribute, int pos) { }
        public void handleEndTag(Tag t, final int pos) {  }
        public void handleSimpleTag(Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, final int pos) { }
        public void handleComment(final char[] data, final int pos) { }
        public void handleError(final java.lang.String errMsg, final int pos) { }
    };
    parserDelegator.parse(new StringReader(html), parserCallback, true);

    String text = "";

    for(String s : list) {
        text += " " + s;
    }

    return text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

import java.io.*;

```
public class Html2TextWithRegExp {


public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("java-new.html"));
 String line;
 while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null) {
   sb.append(line);
   // or
   //  sb.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
 }
 String nohtml = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
 System.out.println(nohtml);
 }
}
```

Comment: Why did you create an empty constructor?