# How to remove HTML element of String?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to remove HTML of string in Java.

```
<hr><b><strong>Task Details</strong></b><hr><b>Date Created: </b> 01/06/2014 07:55pm<br><b>Date Modified: </b> 01/06/2014 07:55pm<br><b>Assigned to: </b> Administrator<br><b>Created By: </b> Administrator<br><b>Status: </b> Not Started<br><b>Description: </b> Test Description<br>.
```

Above is my string and I want to remove HTML tags.

Comment: Are these HTML tags? The input does not seem to have HTML tags.

Comment: the question is not clear enough. What string are you talking about and what HTML tag ? Can you please elaborate the question and mention what is it that you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.  So which language are you using?

Comment: I'm just going to leave both [java] and [javascript] in the question until you figure out which language you're using... please retag it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will work:

```
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

It uses regular expressions to remove all HTML tags in a string.

More specifically, it removes all XML like tags from a string. So <1234> will be removed even though it is not a valid HTML tag. But its good for most intents and purpouses.

Hope this helps.

This is actually dead simple with [Jsoup.](http://jsoup.org/)

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Comment: -1 The first part of your answer up to the "Hope this helps" is copied **verbatim** and **unattributed** from [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4432579/147346). Unless you're the same poster, that's a big netiquette no-no.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jsoup library for it.

```
String str="<h3>My Text</h3>";
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(str).text());
```

The above code strip all htms tags and give text left as output