# Replace String starts from <\

Tags: java, string, replace

How can we replace all the string of a sentence that start from `<\` and end `>`

Is there any way available for this.

for now i am replacing each word manually.

example : -

```
test = test.replace("</tr>", "");
        test = test.replace("</html>", "");
```

Comment: Do you need a html parser like Jsoup?

Comment: Obligatory [regex for HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1305253)

Comment: Do you mean `</` instead of `<\\`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013550/how-to-remove-html-element-of-string

Comment: @Jesper yes i want this </anystring> to replace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.replaceAll` method.

From the java docs:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Java code should be:

```
test.replaceAll("<\\/\\w+>");
```