# How to parse HTML-formatted String to plain string?

Tags: android, html, json, parsing

I'm getting a JSON response string similar to this:

```
<strong>B.<\/strong> Because there is no indication of Miss Manette&rsquo;s feelings
```

The string text that I'm receiving is full of tags like `<strong>`, `<em>` and `&rsquo;`
`&ldquo;`
`&rdquo;` etc. How can I parse it to a plain String with same features?

The only way I could think of is replacing such characters and using `Html.fromHtml()` method. Is there a built-in parser available? How could I parse such HTML text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432560/remove-html-tags-from-string-using-java

Comment: use `Html.fromHtml(htmlString).toString()` that's pretty easy and in-built as well

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, parse into a plain string with same features? Do you want the ampersand instead of tags, or tags instead of ampersands?

Comment: I want to replace the text inside <strong> with bold text. I also want to replace texts like `&rsquo;` to apostophe etc. Basically, the output text that I want should be user-readable. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml` only. It'll parse most of the tags supplied and give you the formatted output. The point to note here is that not all of the HTML tags are supported by this method. Checkout [this link](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html) for more information about what tags are supported. Also check [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html), though it's a bit old.

If you know what text you'll be parsing, and you have tags that aren't parsed by fromHtml, your best bet would be to replace them with empty string and then use this method.