# having issue with string in java

Tags: java, string

hi
  I have input as follows:

> "Java technology's versatility,
>   efficiency,
>   `<br/>`
>   `<br/>`
>   platform portability, and security make it the ideal technology
>   for network computing.
>   `<div/>`"

I want to remove `<br/>` & `<div/>` tag from above input.And I want output as follows:
Output:-"Java technology's versatility, efficiency, platform portability, and security make it the ideal technology for network computing."

Please help me how to remove these tags,What will be the java code to get above output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
String unsafe = "Java technology's versatility, efficiency, <br/> <br/> platform portability, and security make it the ideal technology for network computing. <div/>";
String safe = unsafe.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "")
```

Comment: @DJ31, once you have given people enough time to answer and you have a solution you like, you can accept one of them. (Find the tick under the vote number on the left) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) Cleaner to remove HTML stuff.

**Example** :

```
String unsafe = "your string containing html";
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for [htmlParser](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).

Lots of helping hand :

- [Stripping HTML tags in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java)
- [How to remove HTML tags in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How%20to%20remove%20HTML%20tag%20in%20Java)
- [Removing HTML from a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)
- [How to remove HTML tag in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699313/how-to-remove-html-tag-in-java)