# JAVA Regex to remove html tag and content

Tags: java, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove HTML tag in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699313/how-to-remove-html-tag-in-java)
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I want to remove specific HTML tag with its content.

For example, if the html is:

```
<span style='font-family:Verdana;mso-bidi-font-family:
"Times New Roman";display:none;mso-hide:all'>contents</span>
```

If the tag contains "mso-*", it must remove the whole tag (opening, closing and content).

Comment: Personally, I'd use an HTML parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and [how-to-remove-html-tag-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699313/how-to-remove-html-tag-in-java)

Comment: Hasn't these type of questions been asked many times here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) pointed out in his comment, a html parser is the way to go here. If you really want to do it the hard way, here's a regex that works:

```
    String html = "FOO<span style='font-family:Verdana;mso-bidi-font-family:"
        + "\"Times New Roman\";display:none;mso-hide:all'>contents</span>BAR";
    // regex matches every opening tag that contains 'mso-' in an attribute name
    // or value, the contents and the corresponding closing tag
    String regex = "<(\\S+)[^>]+?mso-[^>]*>.*?</\\1>";
    String replacement = "";
    System.out.println(html.replaceAll(regex, replacement)); // prints FOOBAR
```

Comment: And if the style attribute doesn't contain any `mso-` directive... maybe a more generalized regexp would be in order.

Comment: @pap let me quote the OP: _If the tag contains "mso-*", it must remove the whole tag (opening, closing and content)._ My post answers his question, and I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. Shame on me for not reading the question properly :) And I think you underestimate yourself, you seem to have understood my comment just fine, just that I was incorrect ;)

Comment: @pap it was my polite way of saying, I think your comment is wrong ;)