# Regex, removing "<xxxxxxx>" from a string

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a String like this

```
"<xxxxxx125xxxx>

<yy2yy>2</yy2yy>
<yy3yy>3</yy3yy>
<yyhhhhyy>50</yyyyy>
<yyyyy>123</yyyyy>"
```

How can I have an output like:

```
2 3 50 123
```

Well, i'm using Android, but I think that it's a global regex right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove HTML tag in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699313/how-to-remove-html-tag-in-java)

Comment: Try `>\d+<` and remove `>` and `<`

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `xml` or `html` parser? If yes then before you go any farther consider checking already created ones like Jsoup which seems to do exactly what you want: `String data = Jsoup.parse(data).text()`

Comment: I'm trying to get the data inside a table html tags. The tags can vary inside '<' and '>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `<[^>]+>` regex.

```
    String[] string = new String[] { "<yy2yy>2</yy2yy>", "<yy3yy>3</yy3yy>",
            "<yyhhhhyy>50</yyyyy>", "<yyyyy>123</yyyyy>" };

    for (String s : string) {
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", ""));
    }
```

output:

```
2
3
50
123
```