# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed in FF

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess

I have below `XML` file:

```php
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/xml');
  require_once('includes/pdo_connection.php');
  $query = "Select * from photo_category WHERE status='A'";
  $result = DB::instance()->prepare($query)->execute()->fetchAll();
  $output="<juiceboxgallery galleryTitle='FutureFit Gallery'>";
  foreach($result as $row) {
    $cat_id = $row['id'];
    $cat_name = $row['photo_category_name'];
    $query2 = "Select * from photogallery WHERE pcID = '$cat_id' AND status = 'A' order by id desc";
    $result2 = DB::instance()->prepare($query2)->execute()->fetchAll();
    foreach($result2 as $row2) {
      $imgCaption = $row2['img_label'];
      $thumb = $row2['thumb_img'];
      $large = $row2['photo_gallery_image'];
      $output .= "<image imageURL='images/photogallery/large/$large'
          thumbURL='images/photogallery/thumb/$thumb'
          linkURL=''
          linkTarget='_blank'>
          <title>".$imgCaption."</title>
      </image>";
    }
  }
  $output .= "</juiceboxgallery>"; ?>
<?php echo $output; ?>
```

And in `.htaccess` I am using as below:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.xml$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Now when I run this `XML` on my server I get error that `XML` is not well formatted. Error is as below:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
$output= '<juiceboxgallery galleryTitle="FutureFit Gallery">';
```

And in Chrome the error says:

```
error on line 6 at column 50: Document is empty
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Look at this [thread][1] I think you will find your solution from there.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075742/regex-to-strip-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

First check the source of the response document (ctrl+u or cmd+u in the most browser). Make sure that the PHP is executed and not delivered to the browser.

You output content before the `header('Content-type: application/xml');` call. Anything outside the `<?php ..?>` is an output to the browser. In your case the xml declaration.

If your database handling stops the script you have no output. Here is no error handling that I can see.

You might get an error message. Use the developer tools of your browser to take a look at the response and/or check the response source.

The XML is generated as text. Values from the database are added without escaping. Use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape special characters like `<` or `&`. Even better use XMLWriter or DOM to generated the XML and let them take care of the escaping.

Comment: Can u please explain more on this?