# replacing data between html tags

Tags: java, string

I have a string called

```
String MT="Mike<a anystring>anystring2</a anystring3>Tyson";
```

I want to replace it and get

```
MT="Mike Tyson";
```

(I want to use string replace function in java)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to strip HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075742/regex-to-strip-html-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            String MT="Mike<a anystring>anystring2</a anystring3>Tyson";
            String stripped = MT.replaceAll("<[^*]*>", " ");
            System.out.println(stripped);
        }
```

Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075756/876739