# Match paragraph from text file to html file ignoring html tags

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to match text file and html file.

```
"<b>Dog</b> and Cat"
```

this will be equal to

```
"Dog and Cat"
```

I'm using Java.

Comment: Replace `<.*?>` with `""` and compare.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stripping HTML tags in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code segment you will need.

```
String text, html;
BufferedReader br;
int i;int tags=0;

br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter HTML code");//If you want to read ferom file, replace the code
html=br.readLine();
for(i=0;i<html.length();i++){
if(html.charAt(i)=='<'){tags++;continue;}
if(html.charAt(i)=='>'){tags--;continue;}
if(tags==0)text=text+html.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: how about get the starting index of that text from html but ignoring the tags while comparing?. The return value of that function must be index number. Im trying insert some character on that position.

Comment: @mois If it helped then select the tick sign int the left side of my answer