# Extracting variable outside of a loop in a method

Tags: java, html, loops

This is a method to basically get rid of html tags in some text. the method remove is given by the following and I tested it and it works.

```
    public static String remove(String text, String str) {

    int firstIndex = text.indexOf(str);
    int beginofNewIndex = (firstIndex + 1) + str.length();

    if (firstIndex > 0) {
        return text.substring(0, firstIndex) + text.substring(beginofNewIndex);
    } else {
        return text;
    }
}
```

However, when I return "text" as given below, it gives me the same value as when I input it. So let's say the parameter for the method removeAllTags is String text. I input "< b> The boy walked < /b >" but it returns the same thing. Does anyone see anything wrong?

```
    public static String removeAllTags(String text) {

    int textLength = text.length();

    while (textLength > 2) {
        int firstIndex = text.indexOf("<");
        int secondIndex = text.indexOf(">");
        int thirdIndex = text.indexOf("</", secondIndex);
        int fourthIndex = text.indexOf(">", secondIndex);

        if (firstIndex >= 0 && secondIndex >= 0 && thirdIndex >= 0 && fourthIndex >= 0F) {


            remove(text, text.substring(firstIndex, (secondIndex + 1)));
            // remove(text, text.substring(thirdIndex, (fourthIndex + 1))); I will implement this into the code but I am testing with the first remove method first.



        }
        textLength = textLength - 1;
    }
    return text;

}
```

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? Maybe see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your string and condition

```
"< b> The boy walked < /b >"
```

this string of yours has space between <*space*/b>, this gives false result for

```
int thirdIndex = text.indexOf("</", secondIndex);
```

that's why it does not go into the loop and you need to assign text with the returned text

```
text = remove(text, text.substring(firstIndex, (secondIndex + 1)));
```

You can also use regular expression to remove all html tag

```
str.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")
```

Comment: Well I did the space in between mainly because if I don't then stackoverflow will automatically convert it into bolded words but thx

Comment: @LoyalKnight cant you use regular expression instead?

Comment: If you just have to remove the html tags from string you can just do str.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","") as specified in answer also

Comment: But the thing is that html tags have like 2 thingies, one <b> in front and another in the back, the one in the back has a / like </b> and that would not work with the regular expression, but thanks though

Comment: @LoyalKnight No it will remove everything between <> including < and > try this String str = "<b> The boy walked </b>";  System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")); It will print The boy walked

Comment: what if the user decided just to do something like <Hello> or something which is not html?

Comment: This will not handle that scenario but the code that you have written will also not handle that, you can check http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 2):

The key problem is this line:

```
remove(text, text.substring(firstIndex, (secondIndex + 1)));
```

This does nothing.

Java does not pass by reference like C, and Strings are immutable, so any changes made to strings passed in are not reflected outside the method.

Instead, you must *assign* the result back to the variable:

```
text = remove(text, text.substring(firstIndex, (secondIndex + 1)));
```

Whatever other problems there may be with your code, this one is the biggest.

Comment: I tried it with text = remove (text, text.substring(firstIndex, (secondIndex + 1))); but I get an error when I run it : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -13
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
 at htmlprocessor.HTMLProcessor.removeAllTags(HTMLProcessor.java:83)
 at htmlprocessor.HTMLProcessor.main(HTMLProcessor.java:32)
Java Result: 1  Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

```
try this give your comment
change these lines
int beginofNewIndex = (firstIndex) + str.length();
this will point new char after >
and
if (firstIndex >= 0) 
this will accept when < is in first index like <br>hai.
```