# Regex replace all in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string containing some HTML content. I want to replace all the HTML tags and the content within them using Regex in java.

So for example `<a>`,`<a href=""/>`,`</a>` etc. should be removed.

I tried

```
str=str.replaceAll("<\\w*>","");
```

but it replaces only the first occurrence from the string.

How can I replace all the occurrences of this kind from the string.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stripping HTML tags in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you try this,

```
str = str.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

Comment: @TanujWadhwa Match a left angle bracket. Then match 0 or more occurrences of NOT the right angle bracket ... in other words match up to but not including the first right angle bracket (since the "<" match). Then match a right angle bracket.  ..... First match is "<a>" then do it again until all matches replaced.

Comment: is it possible to skip a tag, for eg. <br/> and replace the rest.