# How do I trim the HTML of a webpage to remove tags and only show text content in Java?

Tags: java, html, trim

I have a Java assignment to make a simple GUI web browser that takes in the hostname and filepath of a URL and sends it through a socket to the web server. Then the web server returns the contents of the webpage. After converting that data to a string, I need to first remove everything outside the `<body>` and `</body>` tags, and then remove all of the tags from inside of those to show only text content that the user wants to see. I tried to use the `string.split` method to make two splits after `<body>` and `</body>`, but for some reason I was getting an out of bounds exception. I'm pretty pushed for time so if anyone knows of a simple way to do this I would appreciate it.

Comment: It would help if we knew what your GUI web browser was written in..

Comment: Whoops. I was in a rush. Java

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8282951/2696690

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library It may be helpful for you.

[Example1](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url)

[Example2](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Don't handle HTML data with splitting/regexes. There are libraries which are almost necessary to use if you want to work with HTML correctly.

One of the best known library of this sort is [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). After you integrate it to your project you can get the data in your elements for example like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); //where html is your source
Element divs = doc.select("div");
for(Element div : divs){
    System.out.println(div.text());
}
```

There are a lot of examples and tutorials on their page. Be sure to check out [their cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/).