# Java - Strip all HTML tags using JRE System Library

Tags: java, html, string

I have to remove all html tags from a string in Java.

Is there any simple way to do that using JRE System Library?

Just to be sure you understand, looking around I have found many suggestions, frameworks ([Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) etc.), regular expressions or little code snippets.

Could I do it without introducing dependencies or handling a potentially bugged code?

Comment: I don't understand why you're avoiding external dependencies. The point of having these is so you don't have the grief of having to implement something like the above (which, for the record, will appear relatively trivial but will rapidly show itself to be anything but)

Comment: I'm not against external dependencies. I mean, why should I have a dependency when I can do the same thing, may be easily, with the existing System Library.

Comment: **Question**: if you have this: `abc<u>def</u>ghi` what do you like to have? 1. `abcdefghi` or just `abcghi`?

Comment: My point is that for all but the most trivial cases, the above *isn't* easy

Comment: @PeterRader abcdefghi

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this site:

```
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
```

See [Stripping HTML tags in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java)

Comment: None of the suggested answers remove html tags using a JRE System Library component.

Comment: Have you tried the above? Works fine, but it removes all types of tags ... Do you want to keep non html tags?