# How to remove html tags from a variable and store it into a new variable by using a substring in Java

Tags: html, substring

How can I use a substring to assign values from another string? Basically, I want to create something like: (eventTextNoHTML = eventText - HTML tags)

Here is part of the code:

String eventText; //variable to store the raw event text

```
    //get the 3rd face-off in the game
    eventText = getNthEventByType(3, "FAC", "http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20132014/PL020026.HTM");
    System.out.println(eventText);
```

//        //get the 5th face-off in the game
//        eventText = getNthEventByType(5, "FAC", "http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20132014/PL020026.HTM");
//        System.out.println(eventText);

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar assignment in my Java class. If you decide against using an HTML parser like Jsoup, mentioned by Bajal above, you may opt to use the `substring()` function to retrieve all the characters from the variable using beginIndex and endIndex as its arguments. **Consider if it works for your use case**. You will create these variables as `int`s).

`beginIndex` will be equal to `(eventText.indexOf("\">") + 2)`
-- Note that the backslash within the string "escapes" the quotation mark immediately following it and thus tells the compiler that the quotation mark is actually part of the string and doesn't terminate it.

This lets the `eventText` variable (which contains the raw html) call the `indexOf` function to find either the string (denoted by `"searchstring"`) or character array (denoted by `'searchText'`) that you need to begin counting from and that you need to count to, respectively.

Then once you have created your `beginIndex` (or `startIndex`, or whatever you decide to call it) and your endIndex, then you use the substring() method and pass in the `beginIndex` and `endIndex` arguments. Then you set that equal to `String eventTextNoHTML', like this:

`String eventTextNoHTML = eventText.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);`

Now it's just a matter of printing out your eventTextNoHTML variable. Remember how to concatenate, by using a `+` sign

Let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have used jsoup to achieve this.
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/examples/HtmlToPlainText.html

Here is an example I copied from [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0424.html). (There are few other alternatives listed there as well)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class HTMLUtils {
  private HTMLUtils() {}

  public static String extractText(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
    }
    String textOnly = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString()).text();
    return textOnly;
  }

  public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    FileReader reader = new FileReader
          ("C:/RealHowTo/topics/java-language.html");
    System.out.println(HTMLUtils.extractText(reader));
  }
}
```