# How to strip HTML from a text property of a Qt4 widget?

Tags: c++, html, parsing, qt4

What's the easiest way in terms of coding effort, to change a text property of a Qt4 widget, e.g. QLabel.text, so all HTML tags are removed?

The HTML is simple, typically just one to three tags like  or  and their closing partners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this in the past, although the widget seems like overkill.  [QtextEdit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtextedit.html), the rich text edit block.  What makes this work is that the constructor assumes that the string has  tags.

```
QTextEdit htmlText(HtmlText);  // HtmlText is any QString with html tags.
QString plainText = htmlTextEdit.toPlainText();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use a widget for that, you can use [QTextDocument::toPlainText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html#toPlainText)

```
QTextDocument doc;
doc->setHtml(htmlText);
doc->toPlainText();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are really just looking for a way to strip HTML tags from a string which is not something specific to Qt widgets (unless you want a solution that can take advantage of the rest of the Qt library). Anyway, there seems to be no shortage of hits when searching for "strip html from string". There seems to be 2 general approaches:

- Use a regular expression ([here there be dragons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454))
- Use an html parser

You may find a regex that is good enough for your purposes but you will need a proper html parser to do it right.

This stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078/strip-all-html-tags-except-links) has alot of discussion about the regex option (although the question is looking to strip all tags **except** links).

Since you are using Qt, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser) has an answer with examples of using a parser from that library.

Comment: I'm using Qt4 and suppose it would be easier to use whatever Qt4 has to offer.   In general, anything else would be fine but I don't want to be fussing with converting QStrings back and forth to whatever other format there is.

Comment: Can't blame you there. I use QStrings wherever possible. Qt has made C++ very bearable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not peek under the hood in QTextEdit::toPlainText() source code, and see what is done there?

Comment: I hadn't noticed there was such a thing as toPlainText().  Cool!  Now to see what other widgets have it...