# Strip all HTML tags, except allowed

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I've seen a lot of expressions to remove a specific tag (or many specified tags), and [one to remove all but one specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078/strip-all-html-tags-except-links), but I haven't found a way to remove all except many excluded (i.e. all except `p, b, i, u, a, ul, ol, li`) in PHP. I'm far from good with regex, so I'd need a hand. :) Thanks!

Comment: If you are not using HTML5, you may want to look into: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Or HTML_Safe package from PEAR. It has an option to set list of allowed tags.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) does exactly this.

Comment: It's interesting that `strip_tags` doesn't have an option to strip the content within non-allowed tags. Would have made the function more versatile.

Comment: The http://www.php.net/strip_tags page does have a function that does just this. strip_tags_content by mariusz.tarnaski

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer???????

strip_tags() does NOT exactly this!
The title says: Strip all HTML tags, »»»»»»except«««««« allowed
For strip_tags() it can be specified what to include, NOT what to exclude.

Comment: @icefront - you need to learn to read... Quote from the Doc: `You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which should not be stripped. These are either given as string, or as of PHP 7.4.0, as array`

Comment: @icefront Because it is the answer. Strig_tags accepts second parameter where we can describe tags that should be allowed.

Answer (score 68):

you can do this by using[`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function

> ¶ [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

```
 strip_tags($contant,'tag you want to allow');
```

like

```
  strip_tags($contant,'<code><p>');
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to exclude multiple tags. The original ducumentation isn't that clear about this point.

Comment: How to allow this tag ? I didn't get it work

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.ann24h.com/2017/10/blog-post_89.html">`

Comment: You can use array instead of string starting from php 7.4
`$html_value = strip_tags($contente, ['code', 'p']);`

Answer (score 7):

If you need some flexibility, you can use a regex-based solution and build upon it. `strip_tags` as outlined above should still be the preferred approach.

The following will strips only tags you specify (blacklist):

```
// tags separated by vertical bar
$strip_tags = "a|strong|em";

// target html
$html = '<em><b>ha<a href="" title="">d</a>f</em></b>';

// Regex is loose and works for closing/opening tags across multiple lines and
// is case-insensitive

$clean_html = preg_replace("#<\s*\/?(".$strip_tags.")\s*[^>]*?>#im", '', $html);

// prints "<b>hadf</b>";
echo $clean_html;
```