# Disable all tags except for <a>

Tags: php, html, tags, html-entities

I want to encode (`htmlentities`) or disable all tags except for `<a>` tags.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip all HTML tags, except allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247035/strip-all-html-tags-except-allowed)

Comment: @Juhana The OP needs encode all HTML tags, except allowed, not strip them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After using HTML entities, convert the links back using a RegExp:

```
preg_replace('/&lt;(\/?a(?:|\s[\S\s]+?))&gt;/i', '<$1>', $string);
```

If you want other tags to be removed, use:

```
strip_tags($string, '<a>');
```

Comment: You should add \s after a. Now AFAIU it will allow tags: audio, abbr, acronim, etc.

Comment: @RiaD Thanks for pointing out. I've replaced `a.*?` by `a(?:|\s[\S\s]+?)` for this case. The update also includes a match for newlines, because `<a \nhref="">` is also a valid HTML anchor tag.