# Removing HTML tags in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip all HTML tags, except allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247035/strip-all-html-tags-except-allowed)

I'm new to PHP

Here is my code

```
<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.</p>
```

The expected output:

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

How to remove the tags `<p>`?

Comment: `Google is your friend` for such basic queries

Comment: indeed, i suggest you take a quick look at this string function list from http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `strip_tags()` to remove HTML tags

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
echo strip_tags("<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.</p>");
```

will give you `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

Answer (score 1):

Use `strip_tags()` for stripping out the html tags from your string

Example

```
$strip = '<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.</p>';
echo strip_tags($strip);
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string= '<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.</p>';
$new_string = strip_tags($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str= '<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.</p>';
$new_string = strip_tags($str);
```