# Strip_tags except a href tag in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip all HTML tags, except allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247035/strip-all-html-tags-except-allowed)

I have this code:

```
<?php echo strip_tags($row->message); ?>
```

Now, I need to add exception for the **a href** html tag `<a>`, because now all tags are thrown out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `href` is not an html tag. Do you mean the `a` tag?

Comment: Yup, that's the one! It's called an `<a>` tag. `href` is one of its attributes. By the way, you should really [check the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) first before asking this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
strip_tags($row->message, '<a>');
```

Second argument is made for exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you mean strip everything but the `a` tag? Here is how you can do it - supply a string with exceptions as argument number 2 ([documentation](http://php.net/strip_tags/)):

```
<?php echo strip_tags($row->message, '<a>'); ?>
```