# How to parse html tag with regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, curl

I wanted to parse following html tags contents retrieved through curl by regular expressions.

```
<span class='ui-allscores'>IND - 203/9 (49.4 Ovs)</span>
```

so that output will be `"IND - 203/9 (49.4 Ovs)"`.

I have written following code but it is not working.

```
$one="<span class='ui-allscores'>IND - 203/9 (49.4 Ovs)</span>";
$five="~(?<=<span class='ui-allscores'>)[.]*(?=</br></span>)~";
preg_match_all($five,$one,$ui);
print_r($ui);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using RegEx to parse HTML ([see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2612112)).

Comment: ^ really unhelpful comment.  Of course RegEx can be used to parse the above HTML code.  It is very much up to the task.

Comment: @ThoraciusAppotite: as you can see, several persons tagged the comment of federico-t above as useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$string = "<span class='ui-allscores'>IND - 203/9 (49.4 Ovs)</span>";
```

Dynamic span tag:

```
preg_match('/<span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/si', $string, $matches);
```

Specific span tag:

```
preg_match("/<span class='ui-allscores'>(.*?)<\/span>/si", $string, $matches);

// Output
array (size=2)
  0 => string '<span class='ui-allscores'>IND - 203/9 (49.4 Ovs)</span>' (length=56)
  1 => string 'IND - 203/9 (49.4 Ovs)' (length=22)
```

Comment: Thanks to all for solving my problem.

Comment: some explainations should be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove the HTML tags, Use the php built-in function [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove the html tags.

Another answer on removing html tags [Strip all HTML tags, except allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247035/strip-all-html-tags-except-allowed)

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your regex is the `[.]` part. This is matching only a literal `.`, because the dot is written inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). So just remove the square brackets.

```
 $five="~(?<=<span class='ui-allscores'>).*(?=</br></span>)~";
```

The next problem then is the [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) of `*`. You can change this matching behaviour by putting a `?` behind.

```
$five="~(?<=<span class='ui-allscores'>).*?(?=</br></span>)~";
```

**But the overall point is: You should most probably use a html parser for this job!**

### **See** [**How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)