# How can I allow HTML tags for input without being vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I know that the `<b>` tag is harmless in XSS, but after a test I found that it can be manipulated if an onclick script tag is added to it, for example
`<b onclick="alert('xss');">Hello</b>`

How can I prevent XSS on these low level elements?

Comment: Are you using PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247035/strip-all-html-tags-except-allowed Wow, just saw the tag.

Comment: @Justin `strip_tags()` is not a protection against XSS, though. (Edit: ah, you edited)

Comment: With whitlisting tags and attribs. But even this wouldn't give you full protection against current and future attack vectors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take the input and put in a variable, say: `$output`

```
$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onclick=".*?"/i', '$1', $input);
```

Use the php function, [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("b")[0].removeAttribute("onclick");
document.getElementsByTagName("b")[0].removeAttribute("onfocus");
```

Comment: is there a javascript alternative to this as well? As I want to give users a preview of the comment before php validates it

Comment: thanks @JustinE I didn't really think it would be that simple

Comment: Be sure to mark this as the answer if it works for you. I recommend removing the onfocus, and you should do onhover, attributes as well. Be sure to use strip_tags() as well so the users can only use tags that you have defined  to remove the onclick attribute for...

Comment: I currently use strip_tags to get rid of most of the tags but just forgot about this one. I'm going to sleep now but I will mark this as the answer in the morning if I can get it working.

Comment: can the javascript solution be modified to strip attributes from a string rather than a tag? Thanks

Comment: it can be, just use getElementsById("") instead of getElementsByTagName("") then use the str_replace php function to replace <b> with <b id="data"> on tags that the user inputs, so for exampe, `$value=str_replace("<b>","<b id="data">");` `echo "document.getElementsById("data")[0].removeAttribute("onclick");`

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use a regular expression for this:

```
 <?php
$testStringA = '<b>I am a nice text without any evil characters</b>';
$testStringB = '<b onclick="alert(evil)">I am supposed to be evil. :) </b>';
$pattern = '/<b>[a-zA-z0-9 ]+<\/b>/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $testStringB)){
    // this will NOT execute
    echo "TeststringB matches our pattern";
}
if(preg_match($pattern, $testStringA)){
    echo "TeststringA matches our pattern";
}
?>
```

Will output

```
TeststringA matches our pattern
```

However, the RegEx above does only allow for a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and spaces (see the square brackets), you need to modify this to fit your needs.

**If you are using Javascript:**

The good thing about regular expression that they are, to some degree, portable. I've rewritten the above code in JavaScript to demonstrate it more understandable for you:

```
var re = new RegExp("/<b>[a-zA-z0-9 ]+<\/b>/");
var testStringA = '<b>I am a nice text without any evil characters</b>';
var testStringB = '<b onclick="alert(evil)">I am supposed to be evil. :) </b>';
if(re.test(testStringA)){
    alert(testStringA);
}
if(re.test(testStringB)){
    alert(testStringB);
}
```

Or see the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hz42/

Comment: He is preferring to go with a javascript solution. Very nice answer though. +1 for good code...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Justin. I added a JS example.

Comment: I believe just a `document.getElementsByTagName("b")[0].removeAttribute("onclick");`
 would suffice.

Comment: If you wann to allow the users to use markup, it's the best solution and no, yours won't suffice. He wants to give the user a outlut BEFORE he actually submits the Form, so he won't be able to use strip tags and Whatever is between his b-tag won't be filtered. A script inside the b-tag and boom, XSS.

Answer (score 0):

This function may be a help to someone, it is a Javascript function to get rid of XSS attributes from your string.

```
function strip_attr(e){
var r = e.replace(/(<[^>]+) onclick=".*?"/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onfocus=".*?"/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) ondblclick=".*?"/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmousedown=".*?"/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseout=".*?"/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseover=".*?"/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseup=".*?"/i,"$1");    
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onclick=.*?/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onfocus=.*?/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) ondblclick=.*?/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) style=.*?/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmousedown=.*?/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseout=.*?/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseover=.*?/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseup=.*?/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onclick='.*?'/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onfocus='.*?'/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) ondblclick='.*?'/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) style='.*?'/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmousedown='.*?'/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseout='.*?'/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseover='.*?'/i,"$1");
r = r.replace(/(<[^>]+) onmouseup='.*?'/i,"$1");
return r.replace(/(<[^>]+) class=".*?"/i,"$1").replace(/(<[^>]+) class='.*?'/i,"$1").replace(/(<[^>]+) class=.*?/i,"$1");
}
```

**Edit**
PHP variant of the script with added security

```
function strip_attr($e){
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onclick=".*?"/i','$1',$e);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onfocus=".*?"/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) ondblclick=".*?"/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onmousedown=".*?"/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onmouseout=".*?"/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onmouseover=".*?"/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onmouseup=".*?"/i','$1',$r);

$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onclick=.*?/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onfocus=.*?/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) ondblclick=.*?/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=.*?/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onmousedown=.*?/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onmouseout=.*?/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onmouseover=.*?/i','$1',$r);
$r = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) onmouseup=.*?/i','$1',$r);

$r = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) onclick='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
$r = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) onfocus='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
$r = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) ondblclick='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
$r = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) style='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
$r = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) onmousedown='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
$r = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) onmouseout='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
$r = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) onmouseover='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
$r = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) onmouseup='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
return preg_replace("/(<[^>]+) class='.*?'/i","$1",$r);
}
```