# strip_tags or preg_replace to remove few tags from html?

Tags: preg-replace, strip-tags

I am in dilemma between these two. 
I want to strip  `head` tags ( and everything inside/before including doctype/html) , `body` tag and `script` tags from a page that I am importing via `curl`. 
So first thought was this

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<img><p><a><div><table><tbody><th><tr><td><br><span><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><code><pre><b><strong><ol><ul><li><em>'.$tags);
```

which as you can see can get even longer with HTML5 tags, video   object etc..

Than I saw this here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377509/594423

Can anyone advise the preferred method or show your way of doing this and please explain why and 
possibly tell me which one is faster.

Thank you!

Comment: In other words, you want to extract the content of the body tag?

Comment: yes, exactly and leave all tags inside body ( beside script) in tact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test something like that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);

$result = '';

$bodyNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$scriptNodes = $bodyNode->getElementsByTagName('script');
$toRemove = array();

foreach ($scriptNodes as $scriptNode) {
    $toRemove[] = $scriptNode;
}

foreach($toRemove as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$bodyChildren = $bodyNode->childNodes;

foreach($bodyChildren as $bodyChild) {
    $result .= $dom->saveHTML($bodyChild);
}
```

The advantage of the DOM approach is a relative reliability against several html traps, especially some cases of malformed tags, or tags inside javascript strings: `var str = "<body>";`

But what about speed?

If you use a regex approach, for example:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
<script[^>]*> (?>[^<]++|<(?!/script>))* </script>
|
</body>.*$
|
^ (?>[^<]++|<(?!body\b))* <body[^>]*>
~xis
EOD;

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $content);
```

The result is a little faster (from 1x to 2x for an html file with 400 lines). But with this code, the reliability decreases.

If speed is important and if you have a good idea of the html quality, for the same reliability level than the regex version, you can use:

```
$offset = stripos($content, '<body');
$offset = strpos($content, '>', $offset);
$result = strrev(substr($content,++$offset));
$offset = stripos($result, '>ydob/<');
$result = substr($result, $offset+7);
$offset = 0;
while(false !== $offset = stripos($result, '>tpircs/<', $offset)) {
    $soffset = stripos($result, 'tpircs<', $offset);
    $result = substr_replace($result, '', $offset, $soffset-$offset+7);
}
$result = strrev($result);
```

That is between 2x and 5x faster than the DOM version.

Comment: Thnx bud. how about speed compared to the other two ?

Comment: Amazing. One of the best answers I have seen around. Thank you!