# validating text to accept only some html with php

Tags: php, html

I have a `textarea` and want to validate the content with PHP. The content should only be text and allow only some html tags, not all html tags just a few. How to do that?

Could someone give me an example please?

Comment: Are you talking about a RTF editor? You should look into some plugin like this one : http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: Hi ahmed, welcome to SO.  Try reading this post and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247035/strip-all-html-tags-except-allowed  I'm sorry about the people down-voting your question. You don't deserve that, your question is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: i just wanna to validate the content some way to only accept some text and only some html elements like li and p for example

Comment: if you wish to validate after the form is submitted then use strip_tags() as the link above says and what SuperDJ below says.

Answer (score 2):

use `strip_tags()` if you only want to allow an `a href` use `strip_tags($string, '<a>')` and so on.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php