# How to strip specific tags in already published posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to ask how to strip specific tags in all published post in wordpress, I search before and found that I can use [`strip_tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247035/strip-all-html-tags-except-allowed).

```
<?php strip_tags($contant,'<code><p>'); ?>
```

but i don't know which directory and php files I should put that code.

This is my first time that i need to look for a code, before I just need to search plugin and problem solved, unfortunately not in this case.

Comment: if this is your ist time, than plz share the code.

Comment: <?php
strip_tags($contant,'<code><p>');
?>

sorry sir i am really dont know how this php code work. but in my assumption if i put that code in right place, it would make tag <code> and <p> disappear from my post. my last post was based from this assumption,

Comment: `
   
 
<?php strip_tags($contant,'<code><p>');?>` its working or not?

Comment: Hi @brem. Thanks for contributing to Stack Overflow. You said in an edit that one of the answers solved your question. Rather than editing your question, you should upvote answers that help you and [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the answer than best solved your question by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to tell you where exactly to put this code without seeing your theme, but there's probably a 90% chance this will do what you want.

Your theme very likely has a file in it called functions.php. Open that up and place this code some where in that file (anywhere, probably)

```
function strip_tags_content_filter($content) {
  $filtered_content = strip_tags($content, "<code><p>");
  return $filtered_content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'strip_tags_content_filter' );
```

This adds a filter to anytime the_content function is called. It will run the content through this function (in this case it strips out tags, but could do just about anything, and then returns the resulting filtered content at the end.