# Scala - Strip all html tags from string except links

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to use a regex pattern found on this thread in scala:

[Strip all HTML tags except links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078/strip-all-html-tags-except-links)

```
value.replaceAll("s/<(?!\/?a(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>//g", "")
```

This gives me several compilation errors, all being "Invalid escape character"

What do I need to do to make scala happy with this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Got it working with the following, no need for the s/ or //g at beginning and end of regex string.

```
value.replaceAll("""<(?!\/?a(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>""", "")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try verbatim string literal `value.replaceAll("""<(?!\/?a(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>""", "")` when dealing with regex to suppress Scala's string escaping.

Comment: Perfect thanks, no longer getting any compilation errors. However the regex doesn't seem to have the intended affect, am I using the replaceAll properly? Or is there something else I need to do? Thanks again for the speedy response :)

Comment: I haven't tested it, but you shouldn't need `s//g/`.