# actionscript htmltext. removing a table tag from dynamic html text

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, htmltext

AS 3.0 / Flash

1. I am consuming XML which I have no control over.
2. the XML has HTML in it which i am styling and displaying in a HTML text field.
3. I want to remove all the html except the links.

[Strip all HTML tags except links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078/strip-all-html-tags-except-links)
is not working for me.

does any one have any tips? regEx?

the following removes tables.
var reTable:RegExp = `/<table\s+[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/s;`

but now i realize i need to keep content that is the tables and I also need the links.

thanks!!!

cp

Comment: You don't need to remove something from your html. Just format it as code ==> intend by 4 spaces, or mark the code and use the code format button or press `Ctrl+k`

Comment: I added formatting and brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Probably shouldn't use regex to parse html, but if you don't care, something simple like this:

find `/<table\s+[^>]*>.*?<\/table\s+>/`
replace ""

Comment: var reTable:RegExp = /<table\s+[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/s; removed the tables and everything in it. now i realize I need some of the content inside the tables. i will keep it at it.

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript has a pretty neat tool for handling XML: E4X.  Rather than relying on RegEx, which I find often messes things up with XML, just modify the actual XML tree, and from within AS:

```
var xml : XML = <page>
                  <p>Other elements</p>
                  <table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
                  <p>won't</p>
                  <div>
                      <table><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>
                  </div>
                  <p>be</p>
                  <table><tr><td>3</td></tr></table>
                  <p>removed</p>
                  <table><tr><td>4</td></tr></table>
            </page>;

clearTables (xml);

trace (xml.toXMLString()); // will output everything but the tables

function removeTables (xml : XML ) : void {
    xml.replace( "table", "");
    for each (var child:XML in xml.elements("*")) clearTables(child);
}
```